# How to delete completed kubernetes pod?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I have a bunch of pods in kubernetes which are completed (successfully or unsuccessfully) and I'd like to clean up the output of `kubectl get pods`. Here's what I see when I run `kubectl get pods`:

```
NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
intent-insights-aws-org-73-ingest-391c9384     0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          8d
intent-postgres-f6dfcddcc-5qwl7                1/1     Running            0          23h
redis-scheduler-dev-master-0                   1/1     Running            0          10h
redis-scheduler-dev-metrics-85b45bbcc7-ch24g   1/1     Running            0          6d
redis-scheduler-dev-slave-74c7cbb557-dmvfg     1/1     Running            0          10h
redis-scheduler-dev-slave-74c7cbb557-jhqwx     1/1     Running            0          5d
scheduler-5f48b845b6-d5p4s                     2/2     Running            0          36m
snapshot-169-5af87b54                          0/1     Completed          0          20m
snapshot-169-8705f77c                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-169-be6f4774                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-169-ce9a8946                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-169-d3099b06                          0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          24m
snapshot-204-50714c88                          0/1     Completed          0          21m
snapshot-204-7c86df5a                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-204-87f35e36                          0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          26m
snapshot-204-b3a4c292                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-204-c3d90db6                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-245-3c9a7226                          0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          28m
snapshot-245-45a907a0                          0/1     Completed          0          21m
snapshot-245-71911b06                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-245-a8f5dd5e                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-245-b9132236                          0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-76-1e515338                           0/1     Completed          0          22m
snapshot-76-4a7d9a30                           0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-76-9e168c9e                           0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-76-ae510372                           0/1     Completed          0          1h
snapshot-76-f166eb18                           0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          30m
train-169-65f88cec                             0/1     Error              0          20m
train-169-9c92f72a                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-169-c935fc84                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-169-d9593f80                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-204-70729e42                             0/1     Error              0          20m
train-204-9203be3e                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-204-d3f2337c                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-204-e41a3e88                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-245-7b65d1f2                             0/1     Error              0          19m
train-245-a7510d5a                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-245-debf763e                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-245-eec1908e                             0/1     Error              0          1h
train-76-86381784                              0/1     Completed          0          19m
train-76-b1fdc202                              0/1     Error              0          1h
train-76-e972af06                              0/1     Error              0          1h
train-76-f993c8d8                              0/1     Completed          0          1h
webserver-7fc9c69f4d-mnrjj                     2/2     Running            0          36m
worker-6997bf76bd-kvjx4                        2/2     Running            0          25m
worker-6997bf76bd-prxbg                        2/2     Running            0          36m
```

and I'd like to get rid of the pods like `train-204-d3f2337c`. How can I do that?

Comment: I had similar task but my duplicate pods are created by kubernetes job. in that case you only need deleted the job and the pods automatically deleted.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can do this a bit easier, now.

You can list all completed pods by:

```sh
kubectl get pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded
```

delete all completed pods by:

```sh
kubectl delete pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded
```

and delete all errored pods by:

```sh
kubectl delete pod --field-selector=status.phase==Failed
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent to this using the Kubernetes Python API?

Comment: this works if you are doing it manually, but if you wanted to automate it, how would you do it @pjincz?

Comment: Tip: add a `--dry-run` to see which pods _would_ be deleted, before running the actual command

Comment: maybe I'm lazy, but I always come here to copy/paste this instead of typing it out :)

Answer (score 58):

If this pods created by CronJob, you can use `spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` and `spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit`

**Example:**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
         ...
```

Comment: he is talking about list of pods not jobs.

Comment: Each job is creating pods- I guess he is talking about this (was relevant for my case, thanks)

Answer (score 17):

You can do it on two ways.

```
$ kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pods | grep Completed | awk '{print $1}')
```

or

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep Completed | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod
```

Both solutions will do the job.

Comment: this only works for pods in the default namespace tho

Comment: just add `-n yournamesapce` to both `kubectl` commands.

Answer (score 13):

If you would like to delete pods not Running, it could be done with one command

```sh
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running
```

**Updated** command to delete pods

```sh
kubectl delete pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running
```

Answer (score 6):

As previous answers mentioned you can use the command:

```
kubectl delete pod --field-selector=status.phase=={{phase}}
```

To delete pods in a certain "phase", What's still missing is a quick summary of what [phases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) exist, so the valid values for a "pod phase" are:

> Pending, Running, Succeeded, Failed, Unknown

And in this specific case to delete "error" pods:

```
kubectl delete pod --field-selector=status.phase==Failed
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one liner which will delete all pods which aren't in the `Running` or `Pending` state (note that if a pod name has `Running` or `Pending` in it, it won't get deleted ever with this one liner):

`kubectl get pods --no-headers=true |grep -v "Running" | grep -v "Pending" | sed -E 's/([a-z0-9-]+).*/\1/g' | xargs kubectl delete pod`

Here's an explanation:

1. get all pods without any of the headers
2. filter out pods which are `Running`
3. filter out pods which are `Pending`
4. pull out the name of the pod using a sed regex
5. use `xargs` to delete each of the pods by name

Note, this doesn't account for all pod states. For example, if a pod is in the state `ContainerCreating` this one liner will delete that pod too.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces |grep -i completed|awk '{print "kubectl delete pod "$2" -n "$1}'|bash
```

you can replace completed with CrashLoopBackOff or any other state...

Comment: There are **eight existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **eighty votes**. Why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution. Code only answers are discouraged. Consider adding an explanation as to how/why this code solves the OP's issue. Also include use cases for which it applies or any caveats where it may not work, if appropriate. Or contrast why this may be a preferable solution in certain cases. Links to documentation or other sources for follow up information are also encouraged where applicable. Good, detailed answers are much more likely to receive upvotes. Consider editing your answer with additional info. All the Best.

Comment: @JeremyCaney
This answer works well if you want to delete all "Completed" pods in all namespaces. The other answers only delete pods in the default namespace

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single command to delete all pods that are terminated, Completed, in Error, etc.

```
kubectl delete pods --field-selector status.phase=Failed -A --ignore-not-found=true
```

If you are using preemptive GKE nodes, you often see those pods hanging around.

Here is an automated solution I setup to cleanup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72872547/4185100

Answer (score 0):

I think [pjincz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321036/pjincz) handled your question well regarding deleting the completed pods manually.

However, I popped in here to introduce a new feature of Kubernetes, which may remove finished pods automatically on your behalf. You should just define a time to live to auto [clean up finished Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/) like below:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: remove-after-ttl
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 86400
  template:
    ...
```

Comment: this is automatically delete the whole job(all pods), not precisely delete completed pods when the job is still running on some pods.

Comment: Why would you want to delete Job-related pods before they are all finished? Do you have a specific case in mind?