# How to remove Kubernetes 'shutdown' pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I recently noticed a big accumulation of pods with status 'Shutdown'. We have been using Kubernetes since October, 2020.

Production and staging is running on the same nodes except that staging uses preemtible nodes to cut the cost. The containers are also stable in staging. (Failures occur rarely as they are caught in testing before).

Service provider Google Cloud Kubernetes.

I familiarized myself with the docs and tried searching however neither I recognize neither google helps with this particular status. There are no errors in the logs.

[image: example of bunch of shutdown pods]
[image: pod description only says failed]

I have no problem pods being stopped. Ideally I'd like K8s to automatically delete these shutdown pods. If I run `kubectl delete po redis-7b86cdccf9-zl6k9`, it goes away in a blink.

`kubectl get pods | grep Shutdown | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod` is manual temporary workaround.

PS. `k` is an alias to `kubectl` in my environment.

Final example: it happens across all namespaces // different containers.
[image]

I stumbled upon few related issues explaining the status
https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/28235
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/102820

"When pods were evicted during the graceful node shutdown, they are marked as failed. Running `kubectl get pods` shows the status of the the evicted pods as `Shutdown`."

Comment: What is the value of TerminationGracePeriodSeconds in your configs?
Try to set it for 60 seks or less and check if it'll help.

Comment: Never manually set it. I can see it's 30sec on active pods.

Comment: I'm surprised that neither k8s docs nor GKE docs have anything about the `shutdown` state of a pod.

Comment: what does `describe pod` gives you? Are there any events listed?

Comment: As I understand these pods are like zombie processes. Node that was hosting these pods terminated, but kubelet didn't sent any termination signal to the api server and it's still kind of "pending termination", probably it's a feature to let you know that node went down. I couldn't find anything about "Shutdown" state as well.

Comment: How did you deployed these pods? Are you using any Deployment for your pods or creating the pods directly?

Comment: @EmruzHossain they are deployed directly using manifest files (type: Deployment) from automatic workflow.

Comment: @Pubudu, I found some issues telling that `shutdown` is a state for evicted pods. Appended to the post. `describe pod` events doesn't mention anything about evicting or failure.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55051

Comment: I like workaround offered by Pudbudu. Yes, it's valid workaround to use cronjob for this kind of activity, until we'll get some clarification from GCE maybe.

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Thanks, I'm also going with the cronjob solution. Can't believe this is not mentioned anywhere by GKE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The evicted pods are not removed on purpose, as k8s team says here [1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54525#issuecomment-340035375), the evicted pods are nor removed in order to be inspected after eviction.

I believe here the best approach would be to create a cronjob [2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) as already mentioned.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: del-shutdown-pods
spec:
  schedule: "* 12 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl get pods | grep Shutdown | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Thanks! Since, as you pointed out, it seems to work as intended I will mark this as the solution.

Comment: To clean up pods from all namespaces: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep Shutdown | awk '{print $1,$2}' | xargs -n2 bash -c 'kubectl delete pod -n $0 $1'`

Answer (score 8):

You don't need any *grep* - just use selectors that kubectl provides. And, btw, you cannot call kubectl from the busybox image, because it doesn't have *kubectl* at all. I also created a service account with the right of pods deletion.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: del-shutdown-pods
spec:
  schedule: "0 */2 * * *"  
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: shutdown-deleter
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: deleter
          containers:
          - name: shutdown-deleter
            image: bitnami/kubectl
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
              - "/bin/sh"
            args:
              - "-c"
              - "kubectl delete pods --field-selector status.phase=Failed -A --ignore-not-found=true"
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Just to add to this, to create the `deleter` service account you need to use `ServiceAccount`, `ClusterRole`, and `ClusterRoleBinding` resources. The rules for the `ClusterRole` should be as follows: `rules: [ { apiGroups: [''], resources: ['pods'], verbs: ['list', 'delete'] } ]` (using JSON instead of YAML because comments don't allow multiple lines).

Answer (score 0):

First, try to forcefully delete the kubernetes pod using the below command:

> $ kubectl delete pod <pod_name> -n  --grace-period 0 --force

You can directly delete the pod using the below command:

> $ kubectl delete pod

Then, check the status of the pod using the below command:

> $ kubectl get pods

Here, you will see that pods have been deleted.

You can also verify using the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace) in the yaml file also.

Most programs gracefully shut down when receiving a SIGTERM, but if you are using third-party code or are managing a system you don’t have control over, the preStop hook is a great way to trigger a graceful shutdown without modifying the application.
Kubernetes will send a SIGTERM signal to the containers in the pod.
At this point, Kubernetes waits for a specified time called the termination grace period.

For more information [refer](https://medium.com/tailwinds-navigator/kubernetes-tip-how-to-gracefully-handle-pod-deletion-b28d23644ccc).

Comment: Thanks! There's no issue deleting those pods. It's rather to prevent them accumulating in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Kubernetes doesn't remove evicted and shutdown status pods by default. We also faced a similar kind of issue in our environment.

As an automatic fix, you can create a Kubernetes cronjob which can remove the pod with evicted and shutdown status. The Kubernetes cronjob pod can authenticate using the serviceaccount and RBAC where you can restrict the verbs and namespaces for your utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/hjacobs/kube-janitor .This provide various configurable option to clean up

Answer (score 0):

My take on this problem looks something like this (inspiration from other solutions here):

```
# Delete all shutdown pods. This is common problem on kubernetes using preemptible nodes on gke
# why awk, not failed pods: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54525#issuecomment-340035375
# due fact failed will delete evicted pods, that will complicate pod troubleshooting

---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: del-shutdown-pods
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: shutdown-pod-cleaner
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: shutdown-pod-cleaner
        spec:
          volumes:
          - name: scripts
            configMap:
              name: shutdown-pods-scripts
              defaultMode: 0777
          serviceAccountName: shutdown-pod-sa
          containers:
          - name: zombie-killer
            image: bitnami/kubectl
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
              - "/bin/sh"
            args:
              - "-c"
              - "/scripts/podCleaner.sh"
            volumeMounts:
              - name: scripts
                mountPath: "/scripts"
                readOnly: true
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: shutdown-pod-cleaner
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: shutdown-pod-cleaner
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["delete", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: shutdown-pod-cleaner-cluster
  namespace: kube-system
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: shutdown-pod-sa
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: shutdown-pod-cleaner
  apiGroup: ""
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: shutdown-pod-sa
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: shutdown-pod-cleaner
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: shutdown-pods-scripts
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: shutdown-pod-cleaner
data:
  podCleaner.sh: |
    #!/bin/sh
    if [ $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --ignore-not-found=true | grep Shutdown | wc -l) -ge 1 ]
    then
    kubectl get pods -A | grep Shutdown | awk '{print $1,$2}' | xargs -n2 sh -c 'kubectl delete pod -n $0 $1 --ignore-not-found=true'
    else
    echo "no shutdown pods to clean"
    fi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just set up a cronjob to clean the dead GKE pods.
Complete setup includes RBAC role, role binding, and a service account.

Service account and cluster role setup.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: pod-accessor-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "delete", "watch", "list"]
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-access
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cronjob-svc
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pod-accessor-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: cronjob-svc
  namespace: kube-system
```

Cronjob to clean up dead pods.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: pod-cleaner-cron
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  schedule: "0 */12 * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          name: pod-cleaner-cron
          namespace: kube-system
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: cronjob-svc
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
          - name: pod-cleaner-cron
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            image: bitnami/kubectl
            command:
              - "/bin/sh"
            args:
              - "-c"
              - "kubectl delete pods --field-selector status.phase=Failed -A --ignore-not-found=true"
status: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the discussion here I created the following [kube-clean repository](https://github.com/mokanina/kube-clean) on GitHub and the corresponding [kube-clean helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/kube-clean/kube-clean) on artifacthub.io, that spawns a `CronJob` for each specified namespace.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34694353)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. Hope it helps someone. Run the code below on one line without the comments. Take out what you don't need or add to help someone else.

```
##Get the pods in the mmi-medic namespace in json format
kubectl get pods -n YOUR_NAMESPACE -o json 
## get a certain JSON element in each of the pods
| jq '.items[].status.containerStatuses 
##If the pod is standing in false ready status, sign of completed pod
| select(.[].ready == false) 
##Only if the pod is in completed status
| select(.[].state.terminated.reason == "Completed") 
##Only if pod was created by Kaniko Image builder, lets me know I am deleteing correct pods.
| select(.[].name | test("kaniko")?) 
##Set a date that is 24 hours ago. 86400 is how many seconds in 24 hours
| (now - 86400) as $date 
##Get the date element we will compare against.
| select((.[].state.terminated.finishedAt 
##Get the first chars from value.
| .[:18] + "Z" 
##If the finishedAt Date is longer than 24 hours then delete.
| fromdate) < $date) 
##Get the name of the POD to send to xargs but raw sends it without the double quotes that jq leaves behind not part of value.
| .[].name ' --raw-output 
##Finally if empty dont run xargs otherwise delete the pod by name.
| xargs --no-run-if-empty kubectl -n YOUR_NAMESPACE delete pod
```

I also use this as my image in my K8s cronjob template

```
image: bitnami/kubectl
```