# GKE and Graceful node shutdown with differences concerning pods in Shutdown state

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two GKE clusters, both running `1.20.8-gke.900` for Control Plane as well as nodes, and using preemptible nodes.

According to [GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms#kubernetes_preemptible_nodes)

> On preemptible GKE nodes running versions 1.20 or later, the kubelet graceful node shutdown feature is enabled by default. As a result, kubelet detects preemption and gracefully terminates Pods.

However, on one of these clusters when doing `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` I see many pods in `SHUTDOWN` state, such as

```
kube-system      metrics-server-v0.3.6-9c5bbf784-w8cs2                       0/2     Shutdown   0          2d20h
```

On the other one, there are no such pods, although both have the same config as far as I know (the only difference is that the one without those pods is a private cluster, the other public, but this should not make no difference?)

**Is there any setting or config difference that I have missed?**

Comment: Can you describe one of the shutdown's pod and add the events so we can take a look?

Comment: @CaioT Well AFAIK the cluster with the pods in shutdown state is behaving as expected according to the documentation, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68687716/k8s-pods-stuck-in-failed-shutdown-state-after-preemption-gke-v1-20 
The cluster which does not have such pods is not behaving as I expect.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that both clusters use preepmtible nodes and the only difference is that one of them is private and the other public ?

Comment: well I am. Strangely enough, now I started getting pods in Shutdown state on the other cluster as well but there were no changes. So I guess this cant be reproduced. Maybe some timing issue, although the nodes were upgraded to 1.20 on August 1 respectively 2 (as part of Regular release channel)

Comment: Hi @user140547, any progress? Please note that "Graceful node shutdown" feature is in alpha in Kubernetes `v1.20`. This may explain random behaviour you are experiencing. In `v1.21` version it is in beta.

Source: [Kubernetes blog - Graceful Node Shutdown Goes Beta](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/21/graceful-node-shutdown-beta/), [Kubernetes v1.20 changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.20.md)

Comment: For the time being it is working. It is true that it is Alpha, however it is activated by default on preemptible GKE 1.20 nodes https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#May_03_2021

Answer (score 1):

Posted community wiki based on comments for better visibility.

For now, the issue with pods being in constant `SHUTDOWN` state on the private cluster is gone. Worth to note, that the issue occurred later also on the public cluster.

A possible cause of unexpected and random behavior is that feature "Graceful node shutdown" is in [alpha state](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.20.md#introducing-graceful-node-shutdown-alpha) in Kubernetes `v.1.20`. In Kubernetes `v.1.21` it is in [beta state](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/21/graceful-node-shutdown-beta/).