# GKE: Pods remain in Error state after node scaledown or replacement

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a GKE cluster in version 1.22, on Spot nodes.
Every time a node is being scaled down or replaced, the pods which are running on that node are staying in Error state, and not removed even after the new pods are up and running.
There are no related events in the namespace, and in the pod description I see the following:

```
Status:       Failed
Reason:       Terminated
Message:      Pod was terminated in response to imminent node shutdown.
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Expected outcome: Old pods should be completely removed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is the expected result as Spot nodes have [GracefulNodeShutdown](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#graceful-node-shutdown) enabled.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344231/how-to-remove-kubernetes-shutdown-pods for some options.

Comment: @GariSingh  When does a pod go into Error status, and when does it go into Terminated status with GracefulNodeShutdown enabled.

thanks.